# gwt on mouse down event prevents click events

Tags: events, gwt

I have a widget, a custom panel that on the method onBrowseEvent in case of Event.ONMOUSEDOWN I call prevent default.

For any widget inside that panel, ClickEvent does not work.

Any help, or explanations would be apreciated.

Comment: Do you cancel the event or call preventDefault()?

Comment: Why do you call preventDefault?

Comment: I call prevent default because I want to drag the panel to scroll it, so when I click I want to capture the screen and then scroll it by moving it. Also I want to be able to click the elements inside. I just wanted to know how on mouse down event interferes with click event.

Comment: Have you tried to sink your custom panel also on ClickEvent?